# How to configure a custom serializer for the value of a specified key in a Map

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a Map<String,Object> = new HashMap(). I want to configure a serializer for the value corresponding to the key named "specialKey" (or other keys) in a programmatic way.

I tried to override the parent class (MapSerializer.class) serialization method to implement this. However, I realized it would lose a lot of logic from the original source code. Is there a better approach to accomplish this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.